# nattable: how to disable single cell selection?

Tags: java, nattable

How to disable single cell selection when clicking? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUjRW.png)

I'm trying it that way:

```
class CustomDefaultSelectionBindings extends DefaultSelectionBindings {

    @Override
    protected void configureBodyMouseClickBindings(final UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {
       //do nothing
    }
}

class CustomDefaultSelectionLayerConfiguration extends DefaultSelectionLayerConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected void addSelectionUIBindings() {
        addConfiguration(new CustomDefaultSelectionBindings());
    }
}

final SelectionLayer selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(bodyDataLayer);
selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new CustomDefaultSelectionLayerConfiguration());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `SelectionLayer` without the default configuration

```
final SelectionLayer selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(bodyDataLayer, false);
selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new CustomDefaultSelectionLayerConfiguration());
```

But with the above solution you could still select in the body because of the body mouse drag mode. The easy way would be to not using the `SelectionLayer` anyhow. Not sure about the other requirements you have.

Comment: First of all thank you.

I need the selection layer because I use `CompositeFreezeLayer` to freeze some rows.

Is there any way to disable mouse drag mode?

Comment: Actually the same way you did with the mouse click.